# Grid/Box View to fit all screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridview

My code as below:

html:

```
<div class="gridContainer">
 <div class="grid"></div>
 <div class="grid"></div>
 <div class="grid"></div>
 <div class="grid"></div>
 <div class="grid"></div>
 <div class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.gridContainer{
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
}
.grid{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 float: left;
}
```

The grids will move up/down when the screen size varies either bigger or smaller since there is float left in the grids.
However, there will be some extra spacing on the right side when there is not enough space to fit any grid into it.

Any suggestion on how to calculate the grids width to fit all the screen size?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is lot more to do than just specifying height and width. You should try [this](http://jqueryplugin.net/freewall-creating-dynamic-grid-layouts-desktop-mobile-tablet/#sthash.LKjnG532.uxfs). It's a plugin for grid layout for all devices.

Comment: To make this post useful to future visitors searching for the same problem, you should edit this post to show an example. If that link were to ever break, your answer would be useless. See [answer] for more details. Hope this helps.